# How to listen to a line in input in real time?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, 17.10, audio-recording, obs-studio

I'm setting up an OBS Studio configuration where I connect a handheld console (Nintendo 3DS) to the mic input of my laptop  and then connect my headset through USB. I can "mix" both my audio input sources to the resulting video in OBS itself, by passing the mic input from my headset through Pulseaudio and the console audio input through ALSA, but I want to hear the sound that my console is producing through my headset. I've seen a Terminal command around that activates a loopback, but that one works only through Pulseaudio, in OBS I'm sending the MIC in (the console) through ALSA. Also I would like to avoid using JACK, to make setup a lot more simple.

Is there a simple way I can achieve this?

Comment: Jack. There are graphical tools to configure jack

Comment: I know, but setting up Jack along with all the other stuff I need to set up takes considerable time and effort

Comment: compared to alternate tools not working you will spend even more time and effort not using Jack. Use the graphical tools - http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications . All of those are trivial to install and use. They are available for download pre-compiled - http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications:Cadence